# Автоповорот изображения на php

Tags: php

Возникла такая проблема:
При загрузке изображения на сайт оно обрабатывается библиотекой GD и сохраняется. И если вставлять это изображения на страницу HTML-сайта, то оно будет показано в оригинале.
Можно ли на php сделать так, чтобы какой-то скрипт проверял, имеет ли изображение данные о повороте, и если они есть, то поворачивать согласно им и сохранять.

Answer (score 4):

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']));
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name']);
if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $image = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $image = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $image = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
    }
}
```

// Взято в комментариях php.net